# Image only Shared with Whatsapp but not with other apps in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I am trying to share image using intent. Here is the method that i created

```
public void shareImg(int fileNum)    //Consider fileNum=R.drawable.img
{

    Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + fileNum);
    Intent share=new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent Via ---");

    Intent chooser= Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Via");
    context.startActivity(chooser);

}
```

The image is shared properly with Whatsapp with caption. But when I try to share app with Gmail, Messenger, etc it gives error shown in Toast.

For eg.

Gmail says : Can't attach empty file

Messenger says : Failed to convert to image

Comment: Few apps support the `android.resource` `Uri` scheme.

Comment: For achieve this you need to first save that resource drawable to the storage and then share with the file URI.

Comment: But it works when I choose from gallery or other apps

Comment: @Shabbir Dhangot but why does it only works with whatsapp only.?

Comment: as said by @CommonsWare some apps not `android.resources` URI. so while choosing from library you passing file so they can handle easily. I think you understand

Comment: ok I understood. So what else can I do over this.?

Comment: @ss007 see my posted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can share image using share intent, but you've to decode image to a localized Bitmap

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image");
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), loadedImage, "", null);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
```

loadedImage is the Path of image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps you can perform.

**Step 1**. First create bitmap from drawable

```
Drawable d = ImagesArrayList.get(0);  
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

**Step 2**. Save Bitmap to File

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg";
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Step 3**. Share this image File with fileurl. Share the Image same as you sharing gallery image.

Complete Answer

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.xxxx); // your resource ID here
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/LatestShare.jpg";
OutputStream out = null;
File file=new File(path);
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
path=file.getPath();
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

Comment: Is there any error while you saving. describe what problem you facing with this solution

Comment: It is giving NullPointerException

Comment: I ve tried your Step 3 already. but as i said it didnt worked

Comment: already did that.. actually i was committing a single mistake that produced runtime error

Comment: I m new to stackoverflow, so i need to earn 15 reputation so as to show my vote publicly